# What is mathematical notation for 'is true only when'?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Assume, $B=(c+d)/2$ is true only when $k=0.5$.

All the variables $B,c,d$ and $k$ are arbitrary constants.

My question is, is there any notation in mathematics that can be used to replace the phrase 'is true only when'?

Please help me with this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say $\implies$.

Comment: Is $B = (c + d)/2$ if and only if $ k = .5$? If so, you might simply say "$B = (c+d)/2$ if and only if $k = .5$."

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answers. Yes, I think i can use <=> (if and only if)

Answer (score 0):

If we say that one thing is true only when a second thing is true, that means that the first thing must be false, or else the second must be true. If the first thing is $p$ and the second thing is $q,$ we often write this as $\neg p\vee q$ or $\sim p\vee q,$ where $\neg$ or $\sim$ mean "not" and $\vee$ means "or." We might also think of this as meaning that the first thing being true *implies* that the second thing must be true, which we often write as $p\implies q.$